# Jenkins runs maven goals differently

Tags: maven, jenkins, javadoc, pmd, emma

I use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) to build project and do static analysis of code.
However when I run those command in Jenkins job, reuslt is different.

Locally

```
$ mvn emma:emma pmd:cpd pmd:pmd javadoc:javadoc
```

Then I get 
target\site [image]

In Jenkins job, Build section, Goals and options

```
emma:emma pmd:cpd pmd:pmd javadoc:javadoc
```

Run into error, because target\site\emma folder with reports is missing.[image]

```
...
Emma: looking for coverage reports in the entire workspace: /home/jenkins/jenkins-home/workspace/Atlas_Master_Maven
Emma: no coverage files found in workspace. Was any report generated?
Build step 'Record Emma coverage report' changed build result to FAILURE
...
```

Local is Windows 7 64x, remote Jenkins is CentOS. Both have maven 3.0.4.

Why is this happening, and how to get the same result in Jenkins?

Comment: you should provide full output of the job to the question. what happened before those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking carefully at Jenkins job output, I found that Unit test where not executed, so emma had no data to proceed. Thanks @eis. Yep, there's no magic.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ atlas ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/jenkins/jenkins-home/workspace/Atlas_Master_Maven/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/funshion/base/service/ServiceException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:60)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:83)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.funshion.base.service.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 21 more

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10(default-test)
[JENKINS] Recording test results
forkedProjectSucceeded com.funshion.microlens:atlas:1.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
mojoStarted org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3(default-cli)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:emma (default-cli) @ atlas ---
processing input files ...
mojoSucceeded org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3(default-cli)1 file(s) read and merged in 114 ms
nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files
```